# PuTTY vs ssh.exe on Windows for ssh connections

Tags: ssh, terminal, putty, console

When I want to connect via ssh to Linux servers from my Windows laptop, my main choices are using PuTTY as I have for 20 years, or using the `ssh.exe` that's now default on all Windows systems (Win10+) from a Command Prompt / PowerShell / Windows Terminal session.

I'm really curious about pro's and con's of these options:

- What might make PuTTY better or ssh.exe from a console better?
- Are there features that PuTTY has that ssh.exe on Widnows does not have, and are there feeatures that ssh.exe on a console has that PuTTY does not have?
  Is one more stable than the other?

I guess one difference (simplistic/cosmetic), is that in a console with ssh.exe I can freely change the font size by CTRL + mouse-wheel roll (whereas in PuTTY, we have to muck about in the Settings to change it). What other pro's and con's are there between these two ways to ssh onto other hosts (and most importantly, technical differences that create issues in normal use)?

Comment: You should use what you are familiar with

Comment: Sure, but if there are good reasons to use one over the other, then that is important to know.

Comment: A question seeking our opinion on a topic isn't within scope

Comment: I'm not after opinions. I'm talking about "ssh.exe can do x,y,z, but putty cannot do these things", etc. For example, if I compare Google Docs to Word, I would want to know what works and does not. For someone that is a SuperUser of ssh, he probably has specific technical reasons why he might use putty over ssh.exe (or vice versa), right? Not opinions, but solid technical reasons.

Comment: So you want a list of technical differences between OpenSSH and Putty?  Why does that require a question here on Super User?  If you have a specific question about the differences, that would be within scope, but in my opionion a question seeking just the differences isn't within scope.